# How ConfigureAwait(false) Prevent Ui Deadlocks

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, winforms, task, task-parallel-library

I Know that this question has been asked endlessly, but still. I think i am missing somthing.
When we want updating UI( WinForm UI for the sake of argument ) in asynchronously manner. But we cannot using the async /await keyword and we have to use the ConfigureAwait(false). As i understand it "Tells" the task that it can resume itself on any available thread instead of waiting to to the main thread. Its preventing the deadlock by free the UI for not waiting for the long process to be completed and task is not waiting for the main UI thread to be available.

The following code demonstrate the classical deadlock

```
public void Button_Click()
{

    SomeTextBox.Text =LongProcessAsync().Result;
}
```

So now my question start :). How eventually UI thread update UI after long proccess task has completed.

Is it because task passing the result to another UI process to complete the job ?
How UI queue message related to that parts ?
When saying only one thread updating the ui , does it mean that this thread live for the all life cycle of the application or only one thread is updating ui but a new thread can be created and do the stuff ?

Thanks

Comment: *But we cannot using the async /await keyword and we have to use the ConfigureAwait(false)*: who told you that? What's the purpose of a Task? To update the UI after the work has competed? Then you need to resume in the UI Thread, in a way or another. Do you want to control the timing of the update, so it doesn't happen as soon as the async operation completes? Run a Task and use an `IProgress<T>` delegate to receive the update(s), once or each time the Task has new data, which can be cached, eventually. Otherwise, use the async/await pattern. Much depends on the type of the operations.

Answer (score 11):

> I recommend reading Stephen Cleary's blog post on this topic: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) which explains how the deadlock happen and how to avoid it.

Pay attention to the difference of "deadlock" and "blocked UI". Deadlock happens when two threads are waiting for each other, Blocked UI happens when UI thread is busy/blocked and cannot process UI messages. Here using `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't prevent "blocked UI", but prevents "deadlock".

When you write an async library methods which runs a task, to prevent a possible deadlock it's recommended to run your task by `ConfigureAwait(false)`. It's to prevent deadlock even in case the users of your library get the result of your async method by calling `Result` or `Wait`.

`ConfigureAwait(false)` basically tells: not to come back to the original context after this line and continue execution on thread pool thread.

To understand it better, look at this example:

```
// UI code 
1:  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
2:  { 
3:      var result = GetDataAsync().Result; 
4:      MessageBox.Show(result); 
5:  } 

// A library code
6:  public async Task<string> GetDataAsync() 
7:  { 
8:      await Task.Delay(1000); 
9:      return "Data"; 
10: }
```

Considering the following facts:

- In Windows Forms, all UI code executes in a single thread; the UI thread.
- `Result` method of the `Task` blocks the calling thread until the result of the task is ready.

This is what happens here:

- At line 3, `GetDataAsync` will be called and executed in UI thread up to line 8.
- At line 8 a task will be created and will run on thread pool thread and await is telling after running that task, the execution should continue in the previously captured context (Which is UI thread context).
- An uncompleted task returns to the original caller (at line 3) which will be completed in future (after completing task of like 8 and then running line 9).
- Then the `Result` method at line 3 will be executed, which blocks the task until it gets completed and final result of `GetDataAsync` is ready.
- When the awaited task of line 8 completes, the scheduler tries to run line 9 in the UI thread, but the UI thread is blocked! So line 9 cannot be executed and `GetDataAsync` cannot be completed.

A deadlock happens: UI thread is waiting for `GetDataAsync` to complete, and `GetDataAsync` is waiting for main thread to be free to execute rest of the code.

To avoid the deadlock, instead of getting the result of async method by `Wait` or `Result`, you should use `await`. But as I mentioned earlier, in above scenario, if you as a library developer run your task (here `Task.Delay`) by `ConfigureAwait(false)` it prevents deadlock, because it tells not to come back to the original context after this line and continue execution on thread pool thread. So at line 8, it tells to continue in thread pool thread, so while the UI thread is blocked, but line 9 executes and returns data to UI thread and unblock it.

```
// UI code 
1:  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
2:  { 
3:      var result = GetDataAsync().Result; 
4:      MessageBox.Show(result); 
5:  } 

// A library code
6:  public async Task<string> GetDataAsync() 
7:  { 
8:      await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false); 
9:      return "Data"; 
10: }
```

But again, keep in mind, as the UI developer, you should always use `await` for awaiting the `Task` and you should not use `Result` or `Wait`.

Comment: Thanks for your scholarly answer,its helped me a lot, very appreciate it !!.  As you mention, ConfigureAwait(false)  prevents deadlock, because it tells not to come back to the original contex (UI) . But still eventually, the result returned to the blocked UI thread . so if its blocked , how it can display the result to the UI ?

Comment: To make it a bit clearer, the second scenario which uses ConfigureAwait(false):  UI thread is blocked in line 3, waiting for `GetData` which is running on a treadpool thread, it enters to `GetData`, waits for 1 second in line 8, then without going back to UI thread, in line 9 returns result, then execution control goes back to the UI thread, and it unblocks. No deadlock happen but your UI is no more responsive during the execution of `GetData`. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Pay attention to the difference of "deadlock" and "blocked UI". Deadlock happens when  two threads are waiting for each other, Blocked UI happens when UI thread is busy or blocked and cannot process UI messages. Here using `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't prevent "blocked UI", but prevents "deadlock".

Comment: I think I got you, did you mean that the execution of the return (line 9) do not comes from UI thread, Its coming from thread pool and then return to UI (main execution thread) for next execution  ?

Comment: I rephrased the answer a bit, You can read again starting from "Considering the following facts". In addition to Stephen Cleary's article which I linked at top of my answer, you may want to read [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) as well. But I hope my rephrased explanation helps you to get a better understanding of the situation :)

Answer (score 3):

> we cannot using the async /await keyword

Why not? Doing synchronous work will block the UI thread, which will degrade the user experience. It's almost always better to use `async`/`await`.

> it "Tells" the task

Technically, it tells the `await`. This is a common mistake. The method is `ConfigureAwait`, not `ConfigureTask`.

> it can resume itself on any available thread instead of waiting to to the main thread.

Technically, it just avoids the context [that is normally captured by `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). For a UI thread, this context would normally resume on the UI thread. `ConfigureAwait(false)` causes `await` to avoid that context and just resume as though there was no context, i.e., on a thread pool thread.

> Its preventing the deadlock by free the UI for not waiting for the long process to be completed and task is not waiting for the main UI thread to be available.

No. The [deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) occurs because the `await` is waiting for the UI thread to be free *and* the UI thread is blocked on the `async` method to complete. `ConfigureAwait(false)` avoids the deadlock by allowing the `await` to resume on a thread pool thread instead of the UI thread. The UI thread is still blocked on the `async` method. The UI thread is not freed up to do other work, and the user experience is still degraded.

> How eventually UI thread update UI after long proccess task has completed.

In that code sample, the UI thread blocks on the asynchronous code, so it will block (become unresponsive) while that code is running. When the code completes, the UI thread will keep executing, just like any other code. At the end of that method, it returns to its message queue proc, and the application is responsive again.

While there can technically be more than one UI thread, having an application with more than one UI thread is rare. And each UI component would belong to a *specific* UI thread; they can't be shared.

Comment: Sorry, In case with `ConfigureAwait(false)` when execution resumes on another thread from the thread pool, how UI thread is "notified" about completeness if it happens on another thread? I assume that rest of the code after `await` should be executed on UI thread, otherwise updates of UI controls will not work.

Comment: @Basin: When the UI thread blocks on a task, it's just like any other synchronization primitive; it waits for a signal that is set when the task completes. When the UI thread `await`s a task, then it (eventually) returns to its message loop, and when that task completes, it posts a message to the message loop to resume executing the `async` method.

Comment: Thanks, for replay !! what do you mean by saying "returns to its message loop". can please refer me for this topic. I think I don't clearly understand you but maybe  this is  what I been missing

Comment: @user14346079: Every UI thread has a message loop, and when a top-level `async` method does an `await` on an incomplete task, then it returns to the message loop.

Comment: Because most of the times you don't write a code from scratch or not using other libraries that you can't change to make them async. It can be either an old code or code that was not written properly.