# ConfigureAwait , UI, await async

Tags: winforms, async-await, configureawait

I have a small project - WinForms
On .net frameWork - just a small test :

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = GetTitleAsync().Result;
    button9.Text = text;            
}
private async Task<string> GetTitleAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "Hello!";
}
```

As I ran the application ,
Clicking the button: "button9" - caused a dead lock,
(since the thread was hung on the ".result" )

Writing GetTitleAsync() this way:

```
private async Task<string> GetTitleAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return "Hello!";
}
```

solved the deadlock - and the application ran ok.

But I don't understand how ?

I would have expected, that using ".ConfigureAwait(false)" would cause a
situation in which :

"button9.Text = text;" is executed on a different thread than
the one, on which the UI was created,
and an excpetion would be throwed !

but it works excellent !
how??

Comment: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) -- Remove `.ConfigureAwait(false);` from there, change: `private async void button9_Click` and `string text = await GetTitleAsync();`

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false);` causes the continuation to resume on a different *Thread*, but the [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext) is *strong*, the first await will resume in the UI Thread. So will do `Result`. But you don't block on async code.

Comment: I also recommend reading Stephen Cleary's posts on the topic (link in the first comment). I also have to explained it in this answer: [How ConfigureAwait(false) Prevent UI Deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65604324/3110834). You may find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have expected, that using ".ConfigureAwait(false)" would cause a situation in which "button9.Text = text;" is executed on a different thread than the one, on which the UI was created, and an excpetion would be throwed ! but it works excellent ! how??

I recommend reading my [`async`/`await` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html); I try to include everything you need to know about `async`/`await` and their contexts, without getting into too much detail for an intro.

Specifically, there are two points from that post that are worth noting:

- Every `async` method begins executing synchronously, on the calling thread.
- `await` captures a context unless you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

So, walking through this code:

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = GetTitleAsync().Result;
    button9.Text = text;            
}

private async Task<string> GetTitleAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return "Hello!";
}
```

This is what happens, in order, with special attention paid to which thread runs which code:

1. `button9_Click` calls `GetTitleAsync()` on the UI thread.
2. `GetTitleAsync()` calls `Task.Delay(3000)` and gets back a task that will complete in 3 seconds.
3. `GetTitleAsync()` calls `ConfigureAwait(false)` and gets back a configured awaiter that will not resume on the current (UI) context.
4. `GetTitleAsync()` uses `await` to asynchronously wait for the task to complete. This `await` will not resume on the current (UI) context because the `await` has been configured not to.
5. The `await` examines the task and sees it is not complete, so it returns an incomplete `Task<string>` to its caller.
6. `button9_Click` calls `.Result` on that task. This blocks the UI thread until that task completes (i.e., `GetTitleAsync()` is finished executing).
7. Three seconds later, the task returned from `Task.Delay(3000)` completes.
8. `GetTitleAsync()` resumes executing after its `await`. Since this was a configured `await`, it continues executing on a thread pool thread.
9. `GetTitleAsync()` returns `"Hello!"`. This is done on a thread pool thread.
10. By returning a value, `GetTitleAsync()` is now complete, and the `Task<string>` that it returned earlier is now completed with a result value. This completion also happens on a thread pool thread.
11. Since the task is now complete, the UI thread is no longer blocked, and it continues executing `button9_Click`.
12. `button9_Click` executes `button9.Text = text;` on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, it's a great honor for me !  I worship you for your profound knowledge and kindness.