# Why does ConfigureAwait causes a deadlock in the following scenario?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a WinForms application with a single button and a single button Click event handler. In the event handler, I have this code:

NOTE: `DoWorkAsync()` returns a `Task<int>`.

```
var result = obj.DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Implementation of DoWorkAsync():

```
    public async Task<int> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        return 200;
    }
```

This code will deadlock but I am not sure why.  I have configured the task not to continue on the UI thread after `GetResult()` returns. So why does the code deadlock instead of running the next line of code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How ConfigureAwait(false) Prevent Ui Deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603800/how-configureawaitfalse-prevent-ui-deadlocks)

Comment: It depends on the implementation of DoWorkAsync. If inside DoWorkAsync (or inside any of the methods it calls) another async method is awaited without using  ConfigureAwait(false) then and there, then the continuation of that awaited method is scheduled to run on the captured context, which is the UI thread. But it won't ever run, because GetResult() is blocking the UI thread, hence deadlock...

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine It doesn't, it just talks about the concepts the way I understand it. Based on that, it shouldn't dead lock. I am missing something.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I added the implementation of DoWorkAsync(). I know that GetResult() blocks UI, but I shouldn't be returning to the UI thread to do the continuation.

Comment: That's the default behaviour because the [SynchronizationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097471/what-does-synchronizationcontext-do) of the UI thread has been set, so it will continue (queued) on the UI thread. What's the reason that you don't want to use await (async)?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen "What's the reason that you don't want to use await (async)?" - This is just playing around with code and testing my knowledge of async/await. I am not sure what you mean by default behaviour when I clearly override the default behaviour with ConfigureAwait(false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have configured the task

`ConfigureAwait` is for configuring awaits, not tasks. There's nothing that `await`s the result of the `ConfigureAwait`, so that's an indication that it's being misused here.

> I have configured the task not to continue on the UI thread after GetResult() returns.

Not really. As explained above, the `ConfigureAwait` has no effect here. More broadly, the code is (synchronously) blocking on the task, so the UI thread is blocked and then will resume executing after `GetResult()` returns.

> This code will deadlock but I am not sure why.

Walk through it step by step. Read my [blog post on async/await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) if you haven't already done so.

Note that this:

```
var result = obj.DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

is pretty much the same as this:

```
var doWorkTask = obj.DoWorkAsync();
var result = doWorkTask.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

1. Asynchronous methods begin executing synchronously, just like any other method. In this case, `DoWorkAsync` is called on the UI thread.
2. `DoWorkAsync` calls `Task.Delay` (also synchronously).
3. `Task.Delay` returns a task that is not complete; it will complete in 3 seconds. Still synchronous, and on the UI thread.
4. The `await` in `DoWorkAsync` checks to see if the task is complete. Since it is not complete, `await` captures the current context (the UI context), pauses the method, and returns an incomplete task.
5. The calling code calls `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the returned task. This essentially has no effect.
6. The calling code calls `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the (configured) returned task. This blocks the UI thread waiting on the task.
7. 3 seconds later, the task returned by `Task.Delay` completes, and the continuation of `DoWorkAsync` is scheduled to the context captured by its `await` - the UI context.
8. Deadlock. The continuation is waiting for the UI thread to be free, and the UI thread is waiting for the task to complete.

In summary, a top-level `ConfigureAwait(false)` is insufficient. There are [several approaches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) to sync-over-async code, with the ideal being "don't do it at all; use `await` instead". If you want to directly block, you need to apply `ConfigureAwait(false)` on every `await` on the method that is called (`DoWorkAsync` in this case), as well as the transitive closure of *all* methods called starting from there.

Clearly, this is a maintenance burden, and occasionally impossible (i.e., third-party libraries missing a `ConfigureAwait(false)`), and that's why I don't usually recommend this approach.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. It makes perfect sense and I see your point. Thank you so much for explaining so clearly this use case (kudos for the step by step break down). Yea, when I rewrite the call with an await (result = await obj.DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);), the continuation runs on a thread pool thread exactly as it should because the next line "label1.Text = '';" throws an exception, not on the UI thread.

Comment: Oh, btw I did read both of your blog posts on async/await, but it's been a while since I read it and probably forgot some finer details. I have these bookmarked.

Comment: You could mention that the solution in this particular case is `await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);`. The term *"transitive closure"* might be too obscure for the OP to figure it out by themselves!