# UI is unresponsive in winforms when using async methods

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

So I have a few methods that I want to call when my form loads (ideally in the constructor but since async/await doesn't work in the constructor I am using the `Form_Load` event). Originally I was using a separate thread to do this work which was working great. Everything was getting done and the UI was responsive while the work was being done. However, I have read that using async/await is "better", "less resource intensive" and is just generally preferred over creating separate threads. I guess the reasoning is that using async/await uses fewer threads?

But when I use this method as illustrated below, the UI is frozen/unresponsive while the function that takes a few seconds is running.

In my `Form_Load` event I am calling a synchronous method:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckForDriver();
}
```

And then here is my `CheckForDriver` function:

```
private void CheckForDriver()
        {
            System.Management.SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_SystemDriver") { 
            Condition = "Description = 'my driver'" };
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
            ManagementObjectCollection drivers = searcher.Get();
            if (drivers.Count > 0) // valid driver, go to next page
            {
                wizardControl.SelectedTab = startPage;
                task = QueryDeviceAsync(false, new List<Button>());
            }
        }
```

where `task` is a field defined as `private Task task;`

And here is the `QueryDeviceAsync` function, the part that takes some time is the `switcher.GetDeviceAndSize()` function.

```
private async Task QueryDeviceAsync(bool enableForm, List<Button> buttons)
        {
            lastBackEnable = backBtn.Enabled;
            lastNextEnable = nextBtn.Enabled;
            EnableButtons(false, false);
            this.Enabled = enableForm;
            if (buttons != null)
            {
                foreach (Button button in buttons)
                {
                    button.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            await Task.Run(() => switcher.GetDeviceAndSize()); // this function takes a few seconds and this is where the UI becomes unresponsive.
            ThreadFinished?.Invoke(buttons);
        }
```

and then in the `ThreadFinished` event handler, I am doing `await task;` to wait for the `QueryDeviceAsync` function to finish, at which time I update some UI stuff based on what the `switcher.GetDeviceAndSize` function did. I was also confused about whether I can/should update UI stuff in an async method, such as when I am disabling the buttons in the `buttons` list in the `QueryDeviceAsync` function. I know this doesn't work in a second thread and has to be done on the thread that they were created in, but this runs without issues.

My main problem is that the form is still unresponsive while I'm using these async functions. It works fine when I use a separate thread so I'm inclined to just go back to that but I thought I would try to figure this method out.

Comment: "where task is a field defined as `private Task task;`" - _don't_ use mutable class fields for exchanging data between methods - it means your code won't support reentrancy and will have other annoying bugs - always prefer parameters and return values and if it's possible to make a method `static` then you should do that too because these constraints on program design make it much easier to read, follow, understand, maintain, fix, and improve.

Comment: Try declaring your event handler as async, e.g. `private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Does that help?

Comment: no making the event handler async doesn't help, already tried that.

Comment: Have you tried using [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603800/how-configureawaitfalse-prevent-ui-deadlocks)?

Comment: @Dai does that matter? I am calling async methods and using await in `CheckForDriver` so wouldn't it exit the `Form_Load` function before `CheckForDriver` and `switcher.GetDeviceAndSize` are finished? I generally don't really get `await`. I think of it as waiting until the specifed function is finished but im not sure if thats correct.

Comment: Your `CheckForDriver` function (and `Form_Load`) both return almost immediately: neither of those methods do any waiting... nor `await`ing. The `await` in `QueryDeviceAsync` does not affect, capture, join nor delay the UI thread that initially enters `Form_Load`

Comment: based on my reading of that article, I think my issue is "blocked UI" not "deadlock" and the author says `ConfigureAwait` is to prevent deadlock. The function finishes after a few seconds, it doesn't get stuck, but the UI is unresponsive during that time.

Comment: Show us how you're using `ThreadFinished` - how is it defined, and what code subscribes to it? (and you probably should remove it entirely...)

Comment: It's entirely possible that the UI thread is blocked in `ManagementObjectCollection drivers = searcher.Get();` too - as that's not a cheap method either, but you're calling it synchronously in the UI thread.

Comment: `ThreadFinished` is just subscribed to by the main form class that all of these functions are in. It just enables some buttons and changes the `SelectedTab` of my `TabControl` if necessary. I tried moving all that code to the end of the `QueryDeviceAsync` function and that had no effect because by the time it reaches that line, `switcher.GetDeviceAndSize` has already finished which is the slow part! and `searcher.Get()` takes about 50 milliseconds so I don't think thats an issue. The form doesn't load until the code gets to `switcher.GetDeviceAndSize()` since thats what takes a few seconds.

Comment: I still am not sure what the issue is with the above code but I implemented something similar to happen when a button is clicked using `async` and `await` and it works perfectly as it worked before with the thread method. Maybe its just something to do with the constructor and Load event that is weird.

Comment: System.Management uses COM to call the underlying implementation (WMI).  One thing that COM does in a highly invisible way is ensuring that library code stays thread-safe.  When the COM object is created in a single-threaded apartment, like the main thread of a Winforms app is, then it ensures that any calls on such an object are invoked on the same thread that created the object.  In other words, it does the exact equivalent of Control.Invoke().  Which in this case is noticeable by the delay it causes.  Stick with the thread you had before.

Comment: @HansPassant that makes sense because like I said above I implemented similar await / async methods on a button press (which didn't use System.Management at all) and there was no issues with the UI being unresponsive / blocked. Unfortunately it seems the WMI search isn't working quite right, it can still see the driver after I uninstall it which isn't very helpful because I want to notify the user if the driver is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to offload the blocking synchronous work to a worker thread. for example:

```
var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query.ToString());

await Task.Run(() => search.Get());
```