# Auth0Client.LoginAsync throws cannot change thread mode after it is set error

Tags: c#, auth0

I do main Auth0 login in a windows form, and auth0 authentication window appears and it is running without any issues and returns the token. The code used in there is as below.

```
var oidClient = new Auth0Client(options);
LoginResult result = await oidClient.LoginAsync();
```

I am trying to implement auth0 login on another windows form, when the token obtained from the main authentication process is expired. In there, I am unable to use the above code, it is not working, code is nonstop running. There seems to be a async deadlock situation happening. So I tried Try 1 and Try 3. none of them fixed the issue. Try 1 is returning "Cannot change thread mode after it is set error".  The auth0 authentication window is not appearing in any of these approaches. Could anybody please help me with the auth0 authentication here?

Code :

```
 public LoginResult AuthenticateViaAuth0()
    {
        try
        {
            if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());
            }

            var options = new Auth0ClientOptions
            {
                ClientId = WConstants.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
                Domain = WConstants.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
                EnableTelemetry = true,
                RedirectUri = WConstants.AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI
            };
            
            //try 1
            var oidClient = new Auth0Client(options);
            var result = Task.Run(async () => await oidClient.LoginAsync());
            //cannot change threadmode after it is set error
            return result.Result;

            //try 2
            //loginResult = await oidClient.LoginAsync();
            //running nonstop

            //try3
            //Task<LoginResult> rr = oidClient.LoginAsync();
            //var result = rr.ConfigureAwait(false);
            //bool state = true;

            //do
            //{
            //    if (rr.IsCompleted)
            //    {
            //        state = false;
            //        this.loginResult = result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            //    }
            //} while (state = true);
            //return this.loginResult;
            //Running not stopping
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //exception handling
        }
    }
```

Note :
Not sure whether this information is relevant with the diagnosis, on the same form, I send requests for GraphQL api, there I had to handle async deadlock situation. It is running and returning data without other issues.

```
 var graphQLResponse = Task.Run(async () => await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<Template>(graphQLRequest)).Result;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go async all the way? That should already remove a possible deadlock?

Comment: I suggest read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603800/how-configureawaitfalse-prevent-ui-deadlocks) and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) to better understand async/await